# Notify agent when any caller entered in twilio queue

Tags: twilio

I am using Twlio Client for my application.

I want to notify agent when any caller comes in Queue.
Right now I am calling Rest API Method for Dequeue first member of the queue on every 5 second.
but It is having some performance issues.

Is there any way to notify agent when caller enters in queue?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think a lot of this depends on the specific experience you want to give your agents.

The simplest solution could be to leverage the part of your application that generates the TwiML containing the `<Enqueue>` verb (putting the caller into the queue).  As part of that generation process you could add some code that uses a technology like socket.io or signalr to sent a real-time notification to the browser client telling the agent that a new caller has just been enqueued.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This only handles a caller entering the queue. Listening for leaving the queue is more problematic because there is no exposed code layer involved.